# Get the order of the forms in a formset automatically, considering that the user can jump over the default order or delete/remove past forms

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm using formset in a form, by adding it as an attribute to the form:

```
 self.whitepaper = WhitePaperFormSet(
            instance=self.instance, 
            prefix=WHITEPAPER_TR,
            data=self.data if self.is_bound else None,
            files=self.files if self.is_bound else None,
            auto_id=False)
```

I need to get/set and order, of the form in formsets. I know that Django use an id/index, can_order, but there are situations like:

1. No Forms completed, the user complete forms number 1 and number 4 (from 4)
2. Form 1 and 3 are already completed, the user deletes/clean form 1 completes 2 and 4, so now I have data in 2,3 and 4

Being documents, can_order is not visible

So the index by itself doesn't help.

So I need to check somehow what is completed, what was removed and number

Comment: Use .`has_changed` to get rid of empty forms

Comment: @CarlBrubaker, if I loop thru them they keep the order of rendering, and overwrite formset validation ? (to understand where to check)

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you use a loop, it always starts with the first one and goes through the order.

If you want to ignore `formset.is_valid()` and let each `form` handle itself:

```py
my_formset = MyFormSet()
for form in my_formset:
    if form.is_valid()
        if form.has_changed()
```

However, you then have to manually delete the deleted forms, which I can't recall right now. I you are mostly concerned about the `order` of everything, I would recommend setting up your `queries` to handle that, either in the `Model` or the `formset` `queryset`.